# PySwip read(X) function on python

Tags: python, prolog, ffi, swi-prolog

when i put this in python

```
from pyswip import *
read = Functor("read",1)
X=Variable()
call(read(X))
```

the response is a prolog shell

```
|:
```

how to make a raw_input instead of the prolog shell?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that you will need to register a new foreign function and call it from prolog code. This **python3** example may help you ([with this python3 version pyswip](https://github.com/f0ma/pyswip3)):

```
from pyswip import Prolog, registerForeign, Atom

def py_read(*a):
    a[0].unify(input("PyInput:"))
    return True

registerForeign(py_read, arity=1)
result = list(Prolog.query('py_read(X)'))
print(result[0]['X'])
```